# Cетка полигонов в google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon

Не получается нарисовать несколько полигонов внутри одного полигона, так сказать сетку. Примерно как рисунке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

У меня получается только основную начертить. А с сеткой проблемы, не понимаю как нужно сделать.

Comment: А Вы хоть как-нибудь пытались уже реализовать? Дополните вопрос своим кодом.

Comment: Пробывал использовать код [как здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144047/google-maps-api-winding-path-within-polygon-with-rotate-grow-shrink-order-option), но не смог переписать под себя, не очень силен в js.